# AppleScript : Safari : Open link in a new tab (Command+Click)

Tags: safari, applescript, tabs, click

I need applescript to open a link listed on a page in a new tab

here is the page HTML

```
<form name="k_1_1_1_1_7_0_7_7_1" method="post" action="/WebObjects/WEBTOOLS.oa/o/GdghsdhHSRHdsh/10.56.14.55"><a href="/WebObjects/WEBTOOLS.oa/o/GdghsdhHSRHdsh/10.56.14.55.0">Billing </a> / <a href="/WebObjects/WEBTOOLS.oa/o/GdghsdhHSRHdsh/10.56.14.55.1.1">Phone</a> / <a href="/WebObjects/WEBTOOLS.oa/o/GdghsdhHSRHdsh/10.56.14.55.2.1">Transactions</a><div style="display:none"><input type="hidden" name="osid" value="GdghsdhHSRHdsh"></div>
</form>
```

I would like to open both Billing and Transaction in new tabs

Comment: Why? This seems oddly specific, and there might be a better solution that's more general.

Comment: I do some investigation on some profile and need to open different links on different tab so I can have a overview of each data